# Assign an option element within a select via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm taking a list from the database and I need to assign each data within that select.

However, I am unable to assign an option element within the select.

Follow my code.

```
let inputCategory = document.querySelector("#modal_form_product select[name='category']");
let option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerText = "5555";
option.value = "5555";
inputCategory.innerHTML += option;
console.log(inputCategory)
```

[image]

Comment: Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the element, so append it. `innerHTML` is only for when you have an HTML string.

```
let inputCategory = document.querySelector("#modal_form_product select[name='category']");
let option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerText = "5555";
option.value = "5555";
inputCategory.appendChild(option);
```

or

```
let inputCategory = document.querySelector("#modal_form_product select[name='category']");
inputCategory.innerHTML += `<option value=5555>5555</option>`;
```

or

```
let inputCategory = document.querySelector("#modal_form_product select[name='category']");
inputCategory.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<option value=5555>5555</option>`);
```